# Why does 'await' break from the local function when called from main()?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await

I am new to asynchronous programming, and while I understand most concepts, there is one relating to the inner runnings of 'await' that I don't quite understand.

Consider the following:

```
import asyncio

async def foo():
    print('start fetching')
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print('done fetcihng')

async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(foo())

asyncio.run(main())
```

Output: `start fetching`

vs.

```
async def foo():
    print('start fetching')
    print('done fetcihng')

async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(foo())

asyncio.run(main())
```

Output: `start fetching` followed by `done fetching`

Perhaps it is my understanding of await, which I do understand insofar that we can use it to pause (2 seconds in the case above), or await for functions to fully finish running before any further code is run.

But for the first example above, why does `await` cause `'done fetching'` to not run??

Comment: Don't call the function in-place: `asyncio.run(main)`! Same for `create_task()`.

Comment: Hi Klaus, sorry I don't understand what you mean- do you mean don't have the parentheses after main? So have main instead of main()?

Comment: Give it a try! And change both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`asyncio.create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task) schedules an awaitable on the event loop and returns immediately, so you are actually exiting the main function (and closing the event loop) before the task is able to finish

you need to change `main` to either

```py
async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(foo())
    await task1
```

or

```py
async def main():
    await foo()
```

creating a task first (the former) is useful in many cases, but they all involve situations where the event loop will outlast the task, e.g. a long running server, otherwise you should just `await` the coroutine directly like the latter

Comment: Thank avi that is very helpful. But one question- in my foo() function above, why does print('done fetching') not execute after the await.sleep() line??

Comment: And instead only the print('start fetching') is executed

Comment: @Patrick_Chong because `foo()` actually starts executing, but then yields to the event loop on the `await asyncio.sleep(2)` line but the main function is exited and the event loop is closed before the 2 seconds are up, for example, if you simply add an `await asyncio.sleep(3)` to the body of your original main function, both will print